# Using hotwords / keywords to start recording speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I want to build a script that uses speech recognition to record what is being said and convert it to text after a keyword has been spoken.

I've had a look at Uberi's speech recognition package, and it provides almost everything I need in terms of recording all the speech and converting it to text.

Is there a way to trigger the recording similar to Alexa each time a keyword is triggered? For example, Person A speaks for 30 minutes about the economic market. During the speech, he mentions words such as "Crisis," "Recession," and "Market Crash."

Is it possible to record and convert to text - perhaps the next 10 seconds of what was said once the keyword was triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something similar to this. You may want to consider using:

- snowboy keyword detection library https://snowboy.kitt.ai/docs to
  detect the keyword. You can have several keywords. You need to define
  the model first.
- Chop the sentence off when there is the first silence, and store it in an audio file
- Invoke a translation service API (e.g. Google) using the previously generated audio file as input. I have tried this one: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/

You can use the microphone or an audio file as input to snowboy.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @EsterGonzalez for the info, are you able to provide a sample code for me to work with so i can test?

Comment: snowboy already provides examples on how to :
1) build a model with the keyword using HTTP-REST APIs
2) test the keyword detection works given an audio input
The input can be via microphone or via audio file. There are examples to identify multiple (two) keywords
Check this example:
https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy/blob/master/examples/Python/demo.py